# How to blur the background screen when click on image in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

in a page small image icon is there when click on that displaying the large size image.Then i need to blur the background of the screen untill he will click on cross icon.
i placed background controls in a grid.
please tell me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not shure if I understand you, but I guess you want to create something like a lightbox.
I guess there's no built-in functionality in XNA to blur something (like the whole screen), but you could try to lay a semi-transparent image (e.g. a fully black .png image with 50% opacity) over the whole screen and put your desired content on top of this.